# Convert decimals to HH:MM:SS

Tags: db2, db2-400

Need a help in converting decimal to `hh:mm:ss` format in `DB2`.

I have a query with some calculation which has an outcome like `0.59` or `1.11` or `2.14`. With the below query, I can change `1.11` to `00:01:11` but it does not work when its less than `1`. In case `0.59`. It does not convert.

```
TIME(TO_DATE(Time,'mi.ss' ) )
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output with 0.59?

Comment: is .59 59 seconds or 60*.59 seconds?

Comment: @Rahul, its giving error. 
".59" cannot be interpreted using format string "mi.ss" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT

Comment: @Hogan,its 59 seconds.

Comment: @Aray:- See the answer from mustaccio, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT expects a string expression. So you need to convert your decimal to string using TO_CHAR and then give it a try.

Comment: @Rahul. It worked. Got the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`TO_DATE()` (which is essentially a wrapper for `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()`) expects a character expression as the first argument. Do not rely on implicit type conversion, use an explicit one:

```
TIME(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Time),'mi.ss' ) )
```

Comment: @Aray:- You can accept the answer if that helped you. (*A right tick mark turns green when clicked*)